# PyAudio issue with libasound_module_conf_pulse.so

Tags: python, audio, alsa, portaudio, pyaudio

I am using the Anaconda Python distribution on a Dell E6520 laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (x86_64) with ALSA and PortAudio installed - "aplay -L" shows the default audio device as "HDA Intel PCH, 92HD90BXX Analog".

After installing portaudio19-dev, I was able to do a successful pip install of PyAudio using the following command:

```
sudo /usr/local/anaconda/bin/pip install --allow-all-external --allow-unverified PyAudio PyAudio
```

However, when I attempt to open a PyAudio object using the following commands in Python:

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

I get the following errors:

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib control.c:953:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
```

Googling the error shows that the "Cannot open shared library..." problem pops up in a variety of contexts (including PyAudio), but none of the suggested solutions are particularly satisfying and some are just plain scary.

I realize problems with low level audio interfaces are difficult to pin down for a variety of reasons, but if this looks familiar to anyone I would very much appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!

---

Additional details - Python version:

```
#python --version
Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.9.1 (64-bit)
```

I am using the PyAudio 'record.py' example from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bastibe/PyAudio/master/test/record.py

When I run it from the command line I get the following:

```
#python record.py 
ALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib control.c:953:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I debug step through the code in PyCharm I get the following output after I step past line 7:

```
/usr/local/anaconda/bin/python /usr/local/pycharm-4.0.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 35435 --file <path to record.py>
pydev debugger: process 5668 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 139.711)
ALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib control.c:953:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0

Process finished with exit code 139
```

I do not get a Python exception.

Comment: Does the creation of the `PyAudio` object actually fail?

Comment: Correct, and rather spectacularly with a seg fault - I will add details to the post

Comment: The segfault points to a bug n PyAudio or PortAudio. There's nothing you can do in Python.